# xelatexmk and emacs

Tags: xetex, emacs, latexmk

For technical reason, I had to set for using emacs as my working environment, as I am able to type directly some Unicode signs that otherwise I cannot code in with Texworks or TeXmaker. At this point, I would like to use xelatexmk in emacs. I have seen some of the actual threads about Latexmk, but I am not really sure how to implement xelatexmk in emacs anyway.

My emacs is the last version in Windows (emacs 23.3) and I am using TeXlive. My .emacs is quite basic and I can post it if it needed. I am asking this question as Ancient Historian working with emacs. 
While I am only asking for a simple setting, I am also raising the point as they might be other users trying to use emacs and latexmk with xelatex, so any answer will be retrievable on line.

Comment: Maybe you can use the solution of http://stackoverflow.com/a/7811232/789593 if you replace "latexmk" with "xelatexmk"? Note that there are some problems with that solution which can be solved by using the solutions of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885853/emacs-latexmk-function-throws-me-into-an-empty-buffer

Comment: @N.N. I will try the solution you said. I have seen it, but the solution there also mentions some changes to .latexmrc file, which I imply it going into my directory, but where? I confess that I have supposed to find a simple "hack" about it, like for Texworks for instance.

Comment: The latexmkrc can be put in for instance your home directory or the current working directory. It can also be called via the `-r` option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124273/compile-xelatex-tex-file-with-latexmk might also help.

Comment: Did you have any luck with the solutions I suggested?

Comment: @N.N.At the end I have not tried it with emacs. I passed to WinEdt beta 7 just after Christmas. I keep emacs working, but WinEdt is much easier to work with, as I only use XeLaTeX anyway.